# Can Swagger describe an array of complex types in querystring for Microsoft Web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, swagger

I am trying to add Swagger doc for my API which uses Microsoft Web API framework.

For example passing an array of GeoPoint (Lat/Lon) objects, Web API expects arrays of complex types that are bound from the querystring to have the following format.

```
/api/Location?points[0][Lat]=1.2&points[0][Lon]=3.4
```

This is working.

My question: is it possible to document this collection format and array type in a Swagger JSON document?

I think the relevant spec is here http://swagger.io/specification/#parameterObject

With type=array and collectionFormat=multi it seems to want to repeat the 'points' parameter, but doesn't know about the array index [0] part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not really.  First, query parameters in the swagger definition are primitive values, or arrays of primitive values.  Next, the assignment of array positions in a query string through substitution is not part of the standard swagger-ui.  You can probably make it work, but I suspect none of the other swagger tooling would know what to do with it.